# Totally destroy an instance

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a game with rounds that last either 100 minutes OR the time required for `totalItemAmount` to reach 500.

If "addPlayer" gets triggered when the game has ended, I want to push that player to next round.

I want to be able to destroy it/create new ones flawlessly.

First game always runs well.

Following games go wrong. To sum it up, I feel like the first game ran isn't being properly destroyed after it ends. Obviously, my code is much much larger than what you see down here, but let me ask you, is there any problem with my structure?

```
function Game(duration, playersForThisRound) {
    console.log('NEW GAME')
    this.playersForNextRound = [];
    this.id = Math.random();
    this.finished = 0;
    this.players = {};
    this.duration = 100;
    this.totalItemAmount = 0;
    this.endTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.end(this);
        return
    }, this.duration * 60 * 1000);
    if (playersForThisRound && playersForThisRound.length > 0) {
        Object.keys(this.playersForNextRound).forEach(function(key) {
            this.addPlayer(this, key.player, key.items)
        });
    }

    return
}

Game.prototype.addPlayer = function(game, player) {
    if (this.finished || this.totalItemAmount >= 500) {
        var playerIsInNextRound = 0;
        Object.keys(this.playersForNextRound).forEach(function(key) {
            if (key.id == player.id) {
                playerIsInNextRound = 1
                key.items.push(items)
            }
        })
        if (!playerIsInNextRound)
            this.playersForNextRound.push({
                "id": player.id,
                "player": player,
                "items": items
            });

        if (game.totalItemAmount >= 500) {
            clearTimeout(game.endTimeout)
            this.end(this);
        }
        return
    }

    if (!game.players[player.id]) {
        game.players[player.id] = new Player(game, player, items);

        game.players[player.id].addItems(game, items, function(added) {
            game.jackpot += added;
            Object.keys(game.players).forEach(function(player) {
                game.players[player].chance = game.players[player].getChance(game.jackpot)
            });

        })

    }

    Game.prototype.end = function(game) {
        game.finished = 1;
        clearTimeout(game.endTimeout)
        setTimeout(() => {
            game = new Game(10, this.playersForNextRound);
        }, 1000 * 60 * 10);
    }
    //To start first game
    var game = new Game();
    module.exports = game;
```

Now in another file:

```
let game = require("./lib/games/roundbased.js");
   let test = setInterval(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           game.addPlayer(game, {
                id: '12345' + i,
                nick: "player" + i
                },
```

Comment: You missed closing the `addPlayer` method. Add `}` before `end`.

Comment: @Tushar _Obviously, my code is much much larger than what you see down here..._

Comment: Yeah guys. Just ignore the typos (sorry about them).  Thing is I can't call "delete" on current game and game = new Game() isn't doing its job effectively.

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RobG what else do you need?

Comment: @needitohelp—the code in the question doesn't demonstrate the behaviour you're asking about, so it's very difficult to provide a useful answer. As it stands you're essentially asking for a code review.

Comment: @RobG If you are having trouble trying to understand it check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707490/bug-exported-object-wont-change-outside-when-modified