# BUG exported object won't change outside when modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, modular-design

File A.js

```
function Game() {
this.id = Math.random();
this.endTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.end(this);
    return
}, this.duration * 60 * 1000);
}
Game.prototype.addPlayer = function(game, player, items) {
        console.log('addPlayer to game.id ' + game.id)
        if (game.totalItemAmount >= 50) {
            clearTimeout(game.endTimeout)
            game.end(game);
        }
        return
    }
Game.prototype.end = function(game) {
game = new Game();
}

let game = new Game();
require('../../tests/B.js')(game)
```

File B.js

```
  module.exports = function (game) { 

    let test = setInterval(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           game.addPlayer(game, {
                playerID: '2134' + i,
                nickname: "player" + i

            },
    }, 4000);
```

Assuming first random `game.id` is 2389423942, `addPlayer` method will keep adding the player to 2389423942 even after the game has finished and the id is now a different one because a new game has started.
Shouldn't the replace of `game` in A.js replace it in B.js too? How to fix the bug?

Answer (score 0):

You copy only a reference of your object to function in `B.js`.

A fix could be to wrap the (reference to the) game object into another object and then modify that reference in there.

Replace in `A.js`

```
let game = new Game();
```

for example with

```
let game = { myGame: new Game() }
```

and in `B.js` `game` with `game.myGame` (where appropriate).

(Beside that, you use a local `game` variable inside `Game.prototype` functions. Have a look at `this` again. I think you got off track here...)

Comment: { myGame: new Game() } will allow me to add players to different game ids or it will create games every time I add a player ¬¬? Please show me how you would end this game without a local reference to this game (in the end game = this)